# How to track untracked files Git

Tags: git

So i do some changes in my project and i did git status in terminal and i get

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   X.php
        modified:   Y.php
        modified:   Z.php

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        A.php
        B.php
```

So my question is if i now do git add . all the 5 files will be add? cuz i need A and B file to merge.

Or i need to use another command to track A and B file again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you read the Git manual, in particular on `git add`? Or taken a Git tutorial? `git add` when without files being specified, or the `-a` switch, only adds files that are already indexed (added from before) by Git for the repository.

Comment: The first line under "Untracked files:" is telling you: *use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed*. Was there a problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can Run

`git add A.php`

`git add B.php`

command